# pygame.display.update causing syntax error

Tags: python, pygame

I have a python program using pygame, but when I run it it gives me a syntax error on the pygame.display.update line. I'm not sure what is causing it. Any help is appreciated!

```py
import pygame, sys
import time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
area = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
red=(255, 0, 0)
black=(0, 0, 0)
fps = 30
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
x=100
y=100
a=0
b=0
pygame.display.set_caption('Reddy For School')
while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
      b=-10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
      b=10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
      a=-10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
      a=10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
      b=0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
      b=0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
      a=0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
      a=0
  x+=a
  y+=b
  pygame.draw.rect(area, red, (x, y, 100, 100)
  python.display.update()
  area.fill(black)
  clock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: Missing closing parenthesis on previous line.

Comment: I am aware that it should be pygame.display.update, above was a typo. The error still persists after this change.

Comment: @Aiden Please edit the question and include the error message and make sure that the code is exactly as you have it on your computer. Otherwise, it's hard to or impossible to know what the problem might be

Comment: Still missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line.

Comment: @Kingsley: Please don't attempt to answer a question by editing it.

Comment: @martineau - the OP explained that the missing `)` was only from pasting the question in.  I couldn't see the point of (a) leaving it in that state, and (b) reading through many comments about it.  it was most expedient IMHO to simply update the question text, as the missing `)` was not the described problem anyway.

Comment: The syntax error on `pygame.display.update()`, the very title of the question, is caused by the missing parenthesis. In what way was it not the described problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, you're missing a parentheses.

I'm not sure what the `python.display.update()` was trying to achieve, but I guess flush the display-updates to the screen.  I substituted this with `pygame.display.flip()`.

There's a couple of painting issues too - the code is drawing a red square, but then filling the screen with black.  These needed to be re-ordered.

Also your main event-loop was not exiting cleanly (under Linux, I could not close the window with the titlebar (x) ).  And finally, you had not parameterised the window width and height.  Soon you will need to calculate something that relies on the window width (e.g.: centering something), so it is best to start with these in a parameter instead of having "400" & "300" all over the code.

```
import pygame, sys
import time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
window_width  = 400
window_height = 300
area = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
red=(255, 0, 0)
black=(0, 0, 0)
fps = 30
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
x=100
y=100
a=0
b=0
pygame.display.set_caption('Reddy For School')
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    # check for closing the window
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
      b=-10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
      b=10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
      a=-10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
      a=10
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
      b=0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
      b=0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
      a=0
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
      a=0
  x+=a
  y+=b
  area.fill(black)
  pygame.draw.rect(area, red, (x, y, 100, 100) )
  clock.tick(fps)
  pygame.display.flip() #quicker process to draw things
pygame.quit()
```